# Fast approx to ln

Tags: python, algorithm

[link to problem](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/00bb/69181895e16bbdd1b575f674432d80064106.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0BkXRBFeDwWOAiNbcnU4YB5ZvbNbJ00ULlaRjXuGsgBFXGy-XCaL2PIjo)

I need to write a fast approx of `ln` in Python and use the 2.4 algorithm. I know I can get the first a_i numbers with:

```html
def f1(x,i):
    a0=(x+1)/2
    g0=np.sqrt(x)
    a=[]
    for j in range(i):
        a0=(a0+g0)/2
        g0=np.sqrt((a0)*g0)
        a.append(a0)
    return a
```

Comment: so what are you stuck on, now you have a_n, next job is implementing the functino d(k,n)

Comment: Tip:don't use numbers,commas, points, functions names ( example: list), and etc. for variable names just use String (word's) and underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `a0` and `g0` inside the for loop, you make a mistake. You need to initialise arrays with those values.

```
def f1(x, n):
    a = [(1 + x) / 2]
    g = [np.sqrt(x)]
    for i in range(n + 2):
        a.append((a[i] + g[i]) / 2)
        g.append(np.sqrt(a[i+1] * g[i]))
    return a[n]
```

In the function above I also keep the notation consistent with the paper. Let me know if this helps, and please flag my comment as an answer to the question if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Yea but im thinking it could be usefull to have it in array so i can calculate the next d(n,k) in the next function. But i have no idea even what to start with. Im also going to plot how bit the error is with n number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

this is how im thinking but i know its wrong

```html
def fast_approx(x,n):
    a = [(1 + x) / 2] 
   
    def f1(x, n):
        a = [(1 + x) / 2]
        g = [np.sqrt(x)]
        for i in range(n + 2):
            a.append((a[i] + g[i]) / 2)
            g.append(np.sqrt(a[i+1] * g[i]))
        return a[n]
    
    def the_big_D(n,k):
        dnull=a[n]
        d=[]
        for i in range(k):
            dnull=(a[n-1] - 4**(-k) * a[n-2]) / (1 - 4**(-k))
            d.append(dnull)

        return d[n]
```